# Incompatible parameter error when calling another smart contract

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm getting this weird error when trying to call the mint entrypoint from another contract... I had additional parameters in the BuyLandRequest and was overriding the `TezosHomepageAdNft.mint` entrypoint, but even when deleting those parameters and that entrypoint, there is still some incompatibility when making the transfer which is hard to parse out from the error.  Any ideas?

> Error: Error in Scenario Variant type error in field mint =
> sp.record(address =
> sp.address('tz1fDKASJtJHBMM6tXadfZGZhVRSC1igwSSJ'), amount = 1,
> metadata = {}, token_id = 1) of type sp.TRecord(address = sp.TAddress,
> amount = sp.TNat, metadata = sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes), token_id
> = sp.TNat).layout((("address", "amount"), ("metadata", "token_id"))) sp.TRecord(address = sp.TAddress, amount = sp.TNat, metadata =
> sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes), token_id =
> sp.TNat).layout((("address", "amount"), ("metadata", "token_id"))) is
> not compatible with sp.TUnit in type sp.TVariant(balance_of =
> sp.TRecord(callback = sp.TContract(sp.TList(sp.TRecord(balance =
> sp.TNat, request = sp.TRecord(owner = sp.TAddress, token_id =
> sp.TNat).layout(("owner", "token_id"))).layout(("request",
> "balance")))), requests = sp.TList(sp.TRecord(owner = sp.TAddress,
> token_id = sp.TNat).layout(("owner",
> "token_id")))).layout(("requests", "callback")), mint = sp.TUnit,
> set_administrator = sp.TAddress, set_metdata = sp.TRecord(k =
> sp.TString, v = sp.TBytes).layout(("k", "v")), set_pause = sp.TBool,
> transfer = sp.TList(sp.TRecord(from_ = sp.TAddress, txs =
> sp.TList(sp.TRecord(amount = sp.TNat, to_ = sp.TAddress, token_id =
> sp.TNat).layout(("to_", ("token_id", "amount"))))).layout(("from_",
> "txs"))), update_operators = sp.TList(sp.TVariant(add_operator =
> sp.TRecord(operator = sp.TAddress, owner = sp.TAddress, token_id =
> sp.TNat).layout(("owner", ("operator", "token_id"))), remove_operator
> = sp.TRecord(operator = sp.TAddress, owner = sp.TAddress, token_id = sp.TNat).layout(("owner", ("operator",
> "token_id")))).layout(("add_operator",
> "remove_operator")))).layout((("balance_of", ("mint",
> "set_administrator")), (("set_metdata", "set_pause"), ("transfer",
> "update_operators"))))

code:

```
class BuyLandRequest():
    def get_type():
        return sp.TRecord(
            address=sp.TAddress,
            amount=sp.TNat,
            metadata=sp.TMap(sp.TString, sp.TBytes),
            token_id=sp.TNat,)

FA2 = sp.import_script_from_url("https://smartpy.io/dev/templates/FA2.py")
class TezosHomepageAdNft(FA2.FA2):
   @sp.entry_point
    def mint(self, params2):
        sp.set_type_expr(params2, BuyLandRequest.get_type())

class TezosHomepage(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, admin, land_nft_address):
        self.init(admin=admin, land_nft_address=land_nft_address)

    @sp.entry_point
    def buy(self, params):
        # create AD NFT here which will be associated with the group of pixels that were purchased
        land_id = sp.len(self.data.lands)
        land_nft_contract = sp.contract(
          BuyLandRequest.get_type(),
          self.data.land_nft_address,
          entry_point = "mint"
        ).open_some(message = "Invalid Interface")
        token_params = sp.record(
            address=sp.sender,
            token_id=1,
            amount=1,
            metadata=sp.map({}),
        )
        sp.transfer(token_params, sp.tez(0), land_nft_contract)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing `sp.set_type_expr(params2, BuyLandRequest.get_type())` with `sp.set_type(params2, BuyLandRequest.get_type())` should fix the issue.

[Setting a type constraint in SmartPy](https://smartpy.io/reference.html#_setting_a_type_constraint_in_smartpy)